# Inheritance best practice to share code when method parameters are different?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a `AWS Redshift` wrapper class that automates similar types of loads from `S3` for me, and I have recently adapted it to work for `Spark` jobs, which don't require a manifest, and instead need a slightly different `COPY` statement.  Other than this one method, all other code is transferable and reusable.  `PyCharm` gives me a warning due to the different method parameters, I'm wondering if there is a "best practice" way to do this.

```
class RedshiftLoader(PrettyStr):
    def __init__(self,
                 s3_credentials=config3.S3_INFO,
                 redshift_db_credentials=config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO_PROD,
                 table_name=None,
                 schema_name=None,
                 dev_db_credentials=config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO,
                 safe_load=False,
                 truncate=False):
...
def copy_to_db(self, database_credentials, copy_from, manifest=False):
        """
        Copies data from a file on S3 to a Redshift table.  Data must be
        properly formatted and in the right order, etc...

        :param database_credentials: A dictionary containing the host, port,
        database name, username, and password.  Keys must match example:

        REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO = {
            'host': REDSHIFT_HOST,
            'port': REDSHIFT_PORT,
            'database': REDSHIFT_DATABASE_DEV,
            'user': REDSHIFT_USER,
            'password': REDSHIFT_PASS
        }
        :param copy_from: The location of the file on the S3 server.
        :param manifest: True if a manifest file is to be used in the copy
        step, False otherwise.

        :return: None
        """
        if not self.table_name:
            raise AttributeError('A table must be specified.')
        s3_access = self.s3_credentials['aws_access_key_id']
        s3_secret = self.s3_credentials['aws_secret_access_key']
        manifest = 'MANIFEST' if manifest else ''
        logger.info('Accessing {table}'.format(table=self.table_name))
        try:
            with ppg2.connect(**database_credentials) as conn:
                cur = conn.cursor()

                if self.truncate:
                    RedshiftLoader.truncate_table(self.table_name, cur)

                load = '''
                COPY {table}
                FROM '{copy_from}'
                CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={pub};aws_secret_access_key={priv}'
                DELIMITER '|'
                GZIP
                TRIMBLANKS
                TRUNCATECOLUMNS
                ACCEPTINVCHARS
                TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
                DATEFORMAT 'auto'
                {manifest}
                '''.format(
                    table=self.table_name,
                    copy_from=copy_from,
                    pub=s3_access,
                    priv=s3_secret,
                    manifest=manifest
                )
                logger.info('Copying to {table}'.format(
                    table=self.table_name))
                cur.execute(load)
                conn.commit()
                logger.info('Copy complete.')
        except ppg2.Error as e:
            logger.critical('Error occurred during load: {error}'.format(
                error=e
            ))
            raise
```

Then the subclass:

```
class SparkRedshiftLoader(RedshiftLoader):
    def copy_to_db(self, database_credentials, copy_from):
        """
        Copies data from a file on S3 to a Redshift table.  Data must be
        properly formatted and in the right order, etc...

        :param database_credentials: A dictionary containing the host, port,
        database name, username, and password.  Keys must match example:

        REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO = {
            'host': REDSHIFT_HOST,
            'port': REDSHIFT_PORT,
            'database': REDSHIFT_DATABASE_DEV,
            'user': REDSHIFT_USER,
            'password': REDSHIFT_PASS
        }
        :param copy_from: The location of the file on the S3 server.  Assumes
        that it is being passed an 's3n' version of the path (common in Spark
        and Hadoop) and will automatically convert to the proper format.

        :return: None
        """
        if not self.table_name:
            raise AttributeError('A table must be specified.')
        s3_access = self.s3_credentials['aws_access_key_id']
        s3_secret = self.s3_credentials['aws_secret_access_key']
        copy_from = copy_from.replace('s3n', 's3')
        logging.info('Accessing {table}'.format(table=self.table_name))
        try:
            with ppg2.connect(**database_credentials) as conn:
                cur = conn.cursor()

                if self.truncate:
                    SparkRedshiftLoader.truncate_table(self.table_name, cur)

                load = '''
                COPY {table}
                FROM '{copy_from}'
                CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={pub};aws_secret_access_key={priv}'
                DELIMITER '|'
                GZIP
                TRIMBLANKS
                TRUNCATECOLUMNS
                ACCEPTINVCHARS
                TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
                DATEFORMAT 'auto'
                CSV
                NULL 'null'
                '''.format(
                    table=self.table_name,
                    copy_from=copy_from,
                    pub=s3_access,
                    priv=s3_secret,
                )
                logging.info('Copying to {table}'.format(
                    table=self.table_name))
                cur.execute(load)
                conn.commit()
                logging.info('Copy complete.')
        except ppg2.Error as e:
            logging.info('Error occurred during load: {error}'.format(
                error=e
            ))
            raise
```

As you can see, the subclass drops `manifest` as a parameter, has a `replace` statement not found in the first, and a slightly different `COPY` command.

Comment: Subclassing doesn't seem like a great choice here since the methods don't have the same interface. You have to know which subclass you're calling to make the call correctly anyway. More importantly these methods seem so similar you can probably refactor them into something that subclasses can then use for a more specialized method.

Comment: Any suggestions on where to start the refactoring?

Comment: You should maybe take this over to the codereview stack exchange. But if you're looking at two gigantic methods that are essentially copypasta of each other, start with extracting the commonalities.

Comment: Can you modify `RedshiftLoader` to make it more flexible, or is that given to you as-is? At the very least, there doesn't seem to be any harm in adding a `manifest` argument to `SparkRedshiftLoader` that is subsequently ignored.

Comment: @chepner I have complete flexibility with this, I suppose I could create a `spark` `boolean` flag in the signature and have the flexibility in a single class without the needless subclassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `RedshiftLoader._copy_to_db` as:

```
def _copy_to_db(self, database_credentials, copy_from, manifest):
        """
        Copies data from a file on S3 to a Redshift table.  Data must be
        properly formatted and in the right order, etc...

        :param database_credentials: A dictionary containing the host, port,
        database name, username, and password.  Keys must match example:

        REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO = {
            'host': REDSHIFT_HOST,
            'port': REDSHIFT_PORT,
            'database': REDSHIFT_DATABASE_DEV,
            'user': REDSHIFT_USER,
            'password': REDSHIFT_PASS
        }
        :param copy_from: The location of the file on the S3 server.
        :param manifest: True if a manifest file is to be used in the copy
        step, False otherwise.

        :return: None
        """
        if not self.table_name:
            raise AttributeError('A table must be specified.')
        s3_access = self.s3_credentials['aws_access_key_id']
        s3_secret = self.s3_credentials['aws_secret_access_key']
        logger.info('Accessing {table}'.format(table=self.table_name))
        try:
            with ppg2.connect(**database_credentials) as conn:
                cur = conn.cursor()

                if self.truncate:
                    RedshiftLoader.truncate_table(self.table_name, cur)

                load = '''
                COPY {table}
                FROM '{copy_from}'
                CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={pub};aws_secret_access_key={priv}'
                DELIMITER '|'
                GZIP
                TRIMBLANKS
                TRUNCATECOLUMNS
                ACCEPTINVCHARS
                TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
                DATEFORMAT 'auto'
                {manifest}
                '''.format(
                    table=self.table_name,
                    copy_from=copy_from,
                    pub=s3_access,
                    priv=s3_secret,
                    manifest=manifest
                )
                logger.info('Copying to {table}'.format(
                    table=self.table_name))
                cur.execute(load)
                conn.commit()
                logger.info('Copy complete.')
        except ppg2.Error as e:
            logger.critical('Error occurred during load: {error}'.format(
                error=e
            ))
            raise
```

The only difference between this and `RedshiftLoader.copy_to_db` is that `manifest` has no default value, and its value is not modified before using it. Now, define `copy_to_db` as follows in each class:

```
class RedshiftLoader(PrettyStr):

    def copy_to_db(self, database_credentials, copy_from, manifest=False):
        manifest = 'MANIFEST' if manifest else ''
        self._copy_to_db(database_credentials, copy_from, manifest)

class SparkRedshiftLoader(RedshiftLoader):

    def copy_to_db(self, database_credentials, copy_from):
        copy_from = copy_from.replace('s3n', 's3')
        self._copy_to_db(database_credentials, copy_from, "CSV NULL 'null'")
```

The private method abstracts out all the common code (which is nearly all of it); the public method provides a place to modify the values of `copy_from` and `manifest` in class-appropriate ways.

Note that `manifest` may not be the best argument name, since it is being used in to fairly different ways. Note, though, that in both cases it is simply a bit of class-specific SQL that is appended to the end of the shared query.

The same refactoring can be done in one class using your idea of a `spark` boolean passed to `copy_to_db` instead.

Comment: One *very* important change you should make: instead of using `format` to build the SQL query, use placeholders and pass the dynamic values as arguments to `cur.execute` to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the code is only run on internal servers with no access externally, but I've definitely thought about that.  Be a good change to make for practice if nothing else:)